# Не загружается картинка из ВКонтакте

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, share, ya-share2

Добрый день!

На странице http://smn72.ru/konkurs/ реализовали раздел «Поделиться работами». Проблема возникает в подсистеме голосования.

Каков ожидаемый принцип работы:

1. Посетитель нажимает на кнопку голосования.
2. Посетителю предлагают поделиться записью с рисунком.

   [image: Голосование]
3. При нажатии на кнопку «Поделиться» отображается соответствующий запрос ВКонтакте (имеется [прямая ссылка-пример](https://vk.com/share.php?url=&title=%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&description=&image=http%3A%2F%2Fsmn72.ru%2Fupload%2Fiblock%2F90b%2F90b7ef66ce7dc66a32c33617277123f7.jpg&utm_source=share2) в обход голосования):

   [image: Подтверждение добавления на стену]

   Прошу заметить, что в запросе в разделе дополнительной информации отображается заголовок (название рисунка), но не сам рисунок. Весь последний месяц рисунок подгружался нормально. Никаких изменений на сайте не производилось.

В чём может заключаться проблема?

---

Участок кода, отвечающий за строку добавления на страницы социальных сетей:

```
<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js" async="async"></script> 
<div class="ya-share2 ya-share2_inited"
     data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"
     data-description=""
     data-image="http://smn72.ru/upload/iblock/494/494a7ac7f78885506b086ed6431e9efd.jpg" 
     data-title="Алиса Яковлева"
     data-counter=""
     data-url="">
```

Итоговый код, который был подставлен на страницу (скопирован из Web-инспектора):

```
<div class="ya-share2 ya-share2_inited" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki" data-description="" data-image="http://smn72.ru/upload/iblock/90b/90b7ef66ce7dc66a32c33617277123f7.jpg" data-title="Аглая Белякова" data-counter="" data-url="">
  <div class="ya-share2__container ya-share2__container_size_m">
    <ul class="ya-share2__list ya-share2__list_direction_horizontal">
      <li class="ya-share2__item ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte">
        <a class="ya-share2__link" href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=&amp;title=%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&amp;description=&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2Fsmn72.ru%2Fupload%2Fiblock%2F90b%2F90b7ef66ce7dc66a32c33617277123f7.jpg&amp;utm_source=share2" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="ВКонтакте">
          <span class="ya-share2__badge">
            <span class="ya-share2__icon"></span>
            <span class="ya-share2__counter ya-share2__counter_visible">1</span>
          </span>
          <span class="ya-share2__title">ВКонтакте</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="ya-share2__item ya-share2__item_service_facebook">
        <a class="ya-share2__link" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?src=sp&amp;u=&amp;utm_source=share2" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Facebook">
          <span class="ya-share2__badge">
            <span class="ya-share2__icon"></span>
            <span class="ya-share2__counter"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="ya-share2__title">Facebook</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="ya-share2__item ya-share2__item_service_odnoklassniki">
        <a class="ya-share2__link" href="https://connect.ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=WidgetSharePreview&amp;st.shareUrl=&amp;utm_source=share2" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Одноклассники">
          <span class="ya-share2__badge">
            <span class="ya-share2__icon"></span>
            <span class="ya-share2__counter"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="ya-share2__title">Одноклассники</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <iframe class="ya-share2__iframe" src="https://yastatic.net/share2/v-1.11.0/frame.html?url=&amp;services=vkontakte%2Cfacebook%2Codnoklassniki" style="border: 0; display: none;position: absolute; left: -9999px;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Задача частично решена, нужно было убрать 2 пустых параметра data-counter="" data-url="" .  ВК работает корректно, FB до сих пор нет

Comment: Facebook берёт картинку из микроразметки, а не из передаваемого параметра. Поэтому единственное возможное решение – сделать по отдельной странице на каждую работу и указывать ссылки на эти страницы.